# IIS stackoverflow

Tags: wcf, iis, stack-overflow

We've been chasing an bug on my WCF web application (W2K3 IIS) which was resulting in a stackoverflow.

To fix it I needed to increase the stack of my application by creating a thread with the amount of memory I wanted to allocate.

But what happens with the child threads? My app creates many threads, will they inherit the value or will I have to set every single thread with the new value?

Edit: If I run the (WCF) services as a console host they work just fine. Also, If I  modify the stack of the w3wp.exe (with the EDITBIN) they also work fine on IIS.
So I need to increase the stack. I know I can create a thread with the stack size (is there another way?) but I need to know what happens with the child threads.

Edit2: We need to define some BIG vectors which are resulting in a stack overflow. So it is not a bug in our system. I really need (have) to increase the stack

Comment: Are you sure it's not a recursive call that never terminates?

Comment: I would look for memory leaks before I tried to increase memory allocation.

Comment: Can you explain why the occurrence of a stack overflow means that you need to increase memory? I don't get it.

Comment: Isn't this the question that Jon Skeet answered in some tiny amount of time months ago?

Comment: is it? I couldn't find anything the answer here... I looked before posting it... could you share a link?

Comment: @sebastian - No, no, I doubt it.  It just triggered a deja-vu moment for me, and I'm trying to figure out why.  I'll do a quick search just in case, but I don't think it's been asked/answered before.  random neurons and all...

Comment: Didn't find anything related.

Comment: Define your BIG vectors on the heap as oppose to the satck....

Comment: This search on StackOverflow may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debugdiag

Comment: Thanks... DebugDiag helped me realize where the problem was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying it myself I can say yes!
Child threads keep the amount of stack set on the parent thread.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to think more carefully about *why* you're getting a stack overflow instead of merely allocating more memory.

Is there some function with a huge amount of local variables or an array that is going on the stack?

Are you sure you aren't leaking somewhere with inadvertent recursive loops?

-Adam

Comment: yes I am...  
I just need to know what happens with the child threads