# IIS StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, stack-overflow

This is yet another variation of the same question where a StackOverflow exception occurs as a result of the 256K stack size while running under IIS. This issue is nothing new and it has been asked several times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595098/iis-stackoverflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577599/opinions-suggestions-on-using-a-thread-in-iis-7-hosted-asp-net-application-to-a))

My question is a little different. The exception is thrown when a client requests data and the WCF service running under IIS 7 tries to serialize a rather large object graph. It actually occurs during the serialization

I can easily reproduce the issue in the development environment by running a retrieve/serialize routine in a thread with a limited stack size:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Thread t = new Thread(DoWork, 262144);
   t.Start();
   t.Join();
   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void DoWork()
{
   var dataAccess = new DataAccess();

   var data = dataAccess.LoadData();

   var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Data>), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, new DataContractSurrogate());

   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, data );
}
```

This simulates the StackOverflow exception just like in IIS. When I change the stackSize parameter passed to the Thread's constructor to 1MB, it works fine...

My question is how can one do this inside of a WCF service method? In other words, in my WCF service method I don't explicitly create a serializer and call WriteObject. How/where can I do this same sort of work around in a thread where I can control the stackSize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the default stack size by changing the PE header of the executable. Use editbin.exe with the /stack argument. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35yc2tc3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I'd rather solve this issue in code. I tried editbin.exe with the /stack switch, but ran into permissions issues since the w3wp application is within the system32 folder. I wasn't able to update the file. In addition, if they were to install a patch or update on IIS, our changes would be overwritten. Any thoughts on how it could be solved programmatically?

Comment: @JohnRussell: I got the impression that you couldn't modify the creation of the thread. If that's the case the only option I'm aware of is to modify the image. Perhaps you would do self hosting and modify that binary instead of the IIS.

Comment: I might be able to modify the creation of the thread, but I'm just not sure how or where that get's done in a process hosted by IIS. There's no explicit statement that creates a serializer and calls WriteObject().